# Poetry install incorrect package on Mac M1 in docker

Tags: python, docker, apple-m1, python-poetry

I have a `poetry.lock` file with dependencies like this

```
[package.dependencies]
package = {version = ">=2.12.0,<2.13", markers = "platform_machine != \"arm64\" or platform_system != \"Darwin\""}
package_for_arm64 = {version = ">=2.12.0,<2.13", markers = "platform_machine == \"arm64\" and platform_system == \"Darwin\""}
```

When I run `poetry install` locally on my Mac M1 machine, poetry installs `package_for_arm64`  package. But when im trying to build an image and run

`RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install`

in my `Dockerfile` it installs `package` package and my code does not work inside my docker container. How do I install `package_for_arm64` inside my image?